# Super User or Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

Should [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385550) be a [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User) question or a [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) one?

The user has mentioned a lot in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385550/syntax-highlight-tmlanguage-in-sublime-text-3-for-packages#comment30439537_20385550), and I am now confused as to which site is the right one for it.

Comment: IMVHO it's a SO question, because it's talking about installation/configuration from a development perspective and/or it's a question about configuration of a development tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a code editor.  It's a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It can work either ways, actually, as Sublime Text is software. However, as it is a code editor, people over at SO may be more suited to solve the problem than the people over at SU.

Comment: Based on the description of the software and the animated GIF that illustrates it, I'd say that it's a tool intended to be used primarily by programmers.

Comment: But both sites do have people that are able to solve the problems. AFAIK, the Exchange's policies regarding these questions have always been to post wherever the question is most likely to obtain the best attention. If the question is then revealed not to be a good fit for site X and instead on site Y, it is moved.

Comment: Putting this in another perspective, would a question about *installing* Sublime Text be a good fit for SO, even though it is a code editor?

Comment: We don't differentiate that way.